# MySQL query to count rows fulfilling two conditions and return an organised list of these counts

Tags: mysql

Our school's got a few extracurricular activities as popular as the one I am running and since it's got hundreds of members, but only a few mentors, we have a strict attendance policy that gets members kicked out **after their third unexcused absence**.

The PHP-JS-MySQL website I created for the purpose of running the activity stores people's attendance to meetings in this MySQL table:

```
meetings_attendance (meetings_id, members_id, attendance, excuse)
```

In this table, `meetings_id` and `members_id` are indices referring to the `int`  primary keys in tables covering, obviously, meetings and members. `attendance` is an `enum` whose values can be `"Pending"`,`"Present"`,`"Absent"` or `"Excused"`, and `excuse` is a `varchar(300)` which can be left null in case the member is present.

Since I'm running the program myself, I do not necessarily wish to include the kicking-out functionality in the website (I'd like to do it manually, contacting each member before they are kicked out and the `status` value in their row of the `members` table is set to `"Inactive"`). I'm trying to get a list of the members' names, email address and phone number, from the `members` table:

```
members (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `phone`........)
```

I have been trying various combinations of MySQL queries to fetch a list of members' absence counts, to no avail. I've tried things like the following, and I have a feeling I should be using `DISTINCT` somewhere, but I can't pinpoint exactly where or how.

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname,
  email,
  phone,
  absences
FROM
  meetings_attendance,
  members
WHERE
  absences = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM meetings_attendance
    WHERE attendance = "Absent"
  )
  AND members.id = meetings_attendance.members_id
```

Comment: I assume it would be, but can you clarify for us that the member is kicked out of only the the specific `meetings_id` for 3 absences, not kicked out of all associated meetings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the absences per member and keep those with a count >= 3 (using GROUP BY and HAVING). Then join the thus found members with the member table and show the results:

```
select
  m.firstname,
  m.lastname,
  m.email,
  m.phone,
  a.absences
from members m
join
( 
  select members_id, count(*) as absences
  from meetings_attendance
  where attendance = "Absent"
  group by members_id
  having count(*) >= 3
) a on a.members_id = m.id;
```

Comment: This seems close, but I suspect it is 3 absences per members_id, per meetings_id, so another column in the `GROUP BY` and maybe another join altogether, to the meetings table.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: I though about this, too. But one meeting is one meeting; how could you miss the same meeting three times? So I am sure this is about members who miss three different meetings, which makes them lose their membership (i.e. they get deleted from the members table or the like).

Comment: Ahh, you may be right. I assumed a meeting (by meetings_id) was a _recurring_ meeting, but if that were the case, we'd probably see another key in meetings_attendance or a datetime.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner @MichaelBerkowski I should have mentioned what the `meetings` table looks like: it has an id, a date and a field that mentions the attendance file, generated by a java program that reads their ID cards to mark them down as "present"... This seems to do exactly what I want it to, thanks! Note, the last line should read `) a on a.members_id = m.id;` but the code is otherwise perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phone, absences FROM members
WHERE id IN
(SELECT members_id FROM 
(SELECT members_id, COUNT(*) FROM meetings_attendance
 WHERE attendance = "Absent"
GROUP BY members_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3 )  AS tab1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to format this code below and tell me whether it solve your problem

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.field1 = table1.id) AS count FROM table1 WHERE table1.field1 = 'value'
```

Comment: if its for 3 absence you can do something like this: SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.field1 = table1.id) AS count FROM table1 WHERE table1.field1 >= '3'